# Install kernel-devel of specific version in fedora 19

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel

So I have different "installed" kernel versions from the running kernel version, on my fedora 19 machine.

To give a more clear idea, here is my terminal output:

```
 [user@home ~]$ uname -r
 3.10.3-300.fc19.x86_64 
 [user@home ~]$ rpm -qa | grep kernel-devel
 kernel-devel-3.10.6-200.fc19.x86_64
 kernel-devel-3.10.4-300.fc19.x86_64
```

When I install Nvidia drivers, it gives me this error that the installed and the running versions are not the same. I want to remove the currently installed 3.10.6-200 and 3.10.4-300 versions, and install the running version ( 3.10.3-300)instead. I don't know how to go about doing it. Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Have you tried with latest nvidia driver? [325.15] - http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-325.15-driver.html Still problem?
Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should be able to run:

```
yum install kernel-devel-3.10.3-300.fc19.x86_64
No package kernel-devel-3.10.3-300.fc19.x86_64 available.
```

But this packages is no longer available. It seems that you have been upgrading your system without actually rebooting it into a new kernel.

On my running system:

```
 yum info kernel|grep -E "Name|Version|Release"
Name        : kernel
Version     : 3.10.4
Release     : 300.fc19
Name        : kernel
Version     : 3.10.5
Release     : 201.fc19
Name        : kernel
Version     : 3.10.6
Release     : 200.fc19

uname -r
3.10.6-200.fc19.x86_64

yum info kernel-devel
Name        : kernel-devel
Version     : 3.10.4
Release     : 300.fc19
Name        : kernel-devel
Version     : 3.10.5
Release     : 201.fc19
Name        : kernel-devel
Version     : 3.10.6
Release     : 200.fc19
```

I advise you to do the following:

Check what kernel you have installed. Check the grub configuration and reboot into the new kernel. After that recompile nvidia drivers.

Unless there is a specific reason for you to stay with your current running kernel, then you will need to look for it. In the Fedora updates repo there is not such package anymore. You can check [here](http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/pub/fedora/linux/updates/19/x86_64/)

Answer (score 2):

It's just complaining because you have newer versions of Kernels installed yet when you booted your system your Grub installation is still defaulting to an older version of the Kernel.

If you're using the EFI version of Grub then you'll likely find your default kernel to boot under `/boot/efi`. You'll want to change it to `set default="0"`, so that it selects the latest Kernel.

Comment: Or it may be just that there hasn't been a reboot for a long time.